# Outlook "Empty Deleted Items folders when exiting Outlook" option is greyed-out

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook

I want to keep my deleted items, but I have "Empty Deleted Items folders when exiting Outlook" option greyed out in my Outlook Options:

[image]

Every time I exit Outlook it prompts me with the message I would much rather not see at all:

[image]

Do you know if it is possible to disable this option anyway? Maybe there is a registry entry, which I can modify to trick Outlook?

My Outlook version is: `Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14131.20296) 64-bit`

Comment: What you want is a contradiction of usage and, long term, destined to failure. Keep items you want in regular folders until you do not want them.

Comment: Also the option here is not greyed out. A school or wor system may be managed by the Outlook Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have enabled the emptytrash registry key, make sure you have set its value as 0 to disable this option. If you could not find this registry key in your environment, please try to manually create the path and values like below:

Registry Path：   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\preferences
Value Name：     emptytrash
Value Type：       REG_DWORD
Disabled Value：0
[image]

[image]

For more information: [Empty the Deleted Items folder when Outlook closes](https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_EmptyDeletedItemsFolder).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is indeed working. Wow, I didn't know Microsoft has documentation available for such things!

Comment: I'm glad your problem has been solved. Have a nice day！